# Есть ли смысл хранить байт в поле varchar(max) в данном случае?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с полями

- ParametrId
- Value [varchar(max)]

Поле Value  может хранить разнотипную информацию, от 1 или 0, до большого текста.
Как резервируется память в поле varchar(max)?
Делают ли такую структуру, как указано выше?
(с одной стороны нет смысла выделять память, если хранить в ячейке 1 или 0, с другой стороны-надо хранить текст результата,который может быть длинным)

Comment: VarChar не потребляет места более, чем необходимо (тело + размер + выравнивание).

Comment: Для больших текстов лучше использовать BLOB-типы, для разнотипных значений лучше использовать разные поля.

Comment: @vp_arth, про разные поля думал, но у меня значения анализов, например Эритроциты-X,Лейкоциты-Y,Параметры типа да/нет , заключение врача-Z(длинное). Конечно можно и разными полями, но хотелось бы динамически, вдруг понадобится ещё поле,где нужен текст или добавился новый анализ....тогда структуру таблицы менять...

Comment: `Заключение врача` - особенное поле, которое присутствует в каждом обследовании. Возможно его стоит вынести в таблицу заказа =)

Comment: @RakzinRoman В данном случае лучше разделить - как минимум формализованные данные в одну таблицу, результаты анализов (одно значение-число) в другую, свободный ввод текста в третью.

Comment: Вы, например, не сможете применить референсные значения к таким текстовым полям. Это разные сущности.

Comment: Судя по документации ms-sql https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx размер хранения varchar 2 байта плюс данные. Но я не понимаю как это может быть ибо varchar(max) 2^31 байт и на хранение такой длины нужны как бы 4 байта ...

Comment: Еще бы придумать как найти вопрос по которому этот по дублю закрыть. аналогичные вопросы проходят с периодом в 1-2 месяца. и мнения всегда несколько разделяются заводить несколько полей под разные типы данных или хранить в одном

Comment: @vp_arth интересно ещё, как сохранять в БД, если был вариант Да,Нет,Ваш вариант. Если сохраню 1-да, 0-нет.....а если в поле Ваш вариант ответ 1 ???

Comment: @RakzinRoman тогда 0 - нет, 1 - да, 2 - другое. т.е. перед "ваш вариант" пишется цифра 2 или любой другой знак означающий нестандартное значение

Comment: Я использую разные типы результатов, текст, число, выбор одного из вариантов, выбор множества вариантов, расчётный параметр,... и несколько других, вплоть до снимка dicom. для каждого типа есть свой набор таблиц. `Да, Нет, Ваш вариант` я бы хранил текстом)

Answer (score 0):

varchar(max) выделяет память и хранится как BLOB только для записей, первышающих 8000 символов. Если символов меньше, то это эквивалент varchar(8000). Так что, это вполне приемлимое решение, если вы не собираетесь вешать на это поле какие-либо индексы, а только выбирать информацию по ключу.